# When exactly Genji climbs and when he stops climbing?

Tags: overwatch

So far Genji's climb ability was quite inconsistent for me, sometimes he climbs high, sometimes he just stops, takes his hands from a wall for no reason and starts falling back.

This video illustrates it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXSlb.jpg I always do the same thing: double jump, then press and hold Space+Forward, sometimes the character climbs for 1 meter, sometimes just for 10 centimeters...

So **what are exact conditions, which should be satisfied so Genji can climb?**

Comment: I believe you have to hold space (jump) while you are doing it

Comment: @n_palum, so I wrote: "I always do the same thing: double jump, then press and hold Space+Forward"

Comment: I'm not sure, but it seems that Genji will not climb high after performing double jump.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Genji and Hanzo can climb walls for a set duration or until they reach a ledge. In your video on King's Row, the ledge on the wall is interrupting your climb, but detection is a little inaccurate so it ends up being inconsistent.

The speed at which you're climbing might also influence the detection in some way, so you might climb past small ledges if you start right below them, but not if you start from further down.

If you started climbing the wall from above that ledge, you should have no trouble getting to the top.

Comment: Thanks. By ledge you mean that yellow 10cm wide strip? But did I really start to climb above the ledge in that first try on the video (the successful one)? For me it looks like I start below it.

Comment: @klm123 As I said, detection is slightly inaccurate for small ledges like that, so sometimes you're able to climb past it. Perhaps your speed might have something to do with it as well, if you pass the ledge quickly enough.

Comment: I see. May be it depends whether I start 5cm lower or higher, so if a hand lands directly on ledge he stops the climbing and if it never does - he doesn't stop.

Comment: @klm123 I doubt the animation has any effect on that. In order to be sure, one would have to take a look at the code for climbing and surface detection. And if Lucio has taught me anything, surfaces in Overwatch are messy.